# Accessing relation after query not returning correct values

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a kind of stupid problem (in my opinion since I am sure this is on my end and I simply overlook sth).

I query a model with a relation to it. When I simply return the whole result everything works fine.

```
$myModel = SampleModel::where('id', '>=', 0)->with('relationToAnother')->get();
```

returning this works as expected.
However, when I try to access the relation while looping over it after I got it back like

```
    foreach($myModel as $m) {
      echo $m->relationToAnother;
    }
```

I simply get back the value of my original modal that is responsible for the connection (e.g. the column from SampleModel and not the relationship).

I am missing sth here and I dont know what.

This is what I am doing after I got $myModel back.

```
$returnValue = array();
  foreach ($myModel as $v) {
   $returnValue[] = $v->relationToAnother->subProperty;
  }
}
```

which throws the error Trying to get property 'subProperty' of non-object. Which is just logic because $v->relationToAnother is still just the value of a column from my model without the relation and not the relation itself.
I didnt include the checks if that property is not null on purpose because that isnt the issue here.

Comment: use `dump($m->relationToAnother);`  or `dd($m->relationToAnother);` instead of `echo`. Can you show the code for your `relationToAnother` relationship.

Comment: the echo was just an example.
What I try to iterate over my model and alter certain value into another array and therefore I need to access the value there. the code is simply public function relationToAnother() { return $this->belongsTo(Another::class);}

Like I said: Returning the original result works without problems. I need to alter it before returning though

Comment: Ok, cool. Please don't simplify your code for the sake of the question as that will often result in the actual issue being obscured. Please can you add the code where you're trying to alter the value.

Comment: @Rwd edited in accordingly

Comment: Is `relationToAnother` the name of a column and a relationship?

Comment: According to what is present in the code I have already available ( i didnt write the original part here, I was tasked to implement an extension): yes. I guess the problem is there?

Comment: @Rwd it was the exaxct issue here... as I sadly cant change that I have to somehow work around it. thanks for the direction here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
$myModel = SampleModel::with('relationToAnother')->where('id', '>=', 0)->get();
```